# Trigger pipeline with a pipeline github branc from another pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I have two Azure DevOps pipelines:
Pipeline A: Master pipeline
Pipeline B: PR review pipeline

So Pipeline B has CI/CD with my github repo and once a pull request has been made, the pipeline jobs are triggered. This pipeline contains only RestAPI task which calls Pipeline A with some template parameters as body.

The question is.
How can I trigger Pipeline A from Pipeline B with the github source branch which is for that particular pull request.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could set PR trigger for source branch in Pipeline B

[image]

[image]

[image]

And Set Pipeline resource trigger for Pipeline A. Then Pipeline A will run automatically after Pipeline B finishes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops

Sample for Pipeline A:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

# Pipeline A YAML pipeline
# We are setting up a pipeline resource that references the Pipeline B
# and setting up a pipeline completion trigger so that Pipeline A
# runs when a run of Pipeline B completes
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: PR # Name of the pipeline resource.
    source: Pipeline B # The name of the pipeline referenced by this pipeline resource.
    trigger: true # Run Pipeline A when any run of Pipeline B completes

steps:
- bash: echo "Pipeline A runs after Pipeline B completes"
```

Comment: I tried the approach and doesn't work. So in the main pipeline(B) which should be triggered by pipeline PR review(A) I have: `resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: PipelineBName
      source: PR_Review(PipelineA)
      trigger: true
  repositories:
    - repository: self
      type: git
      ref: refs/heads/master`

Comment: My Sample is based on your description: "Pipeline A: Master pipeline Pipeline B: PR review pipeline". If it is now main pipeline(B), pipeline PR review(A), you should add pipeline PR review(A) resource trigger into main pipeline(B)


resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: {custom resource name}
    source: Pipeline A Name
    trigger: true

Comment: What is the difference between {custom resource name} and source: {name}?

Comment: I've tried the approach and when PR pipeline is triggered with the pull request branch, it will not trigger the master pipeline with that given branch.

Comment: pipeline: {custom resource name} # identifier for the resource (used in pipeline resource variables)
source: Pipeline A # Name of pipeline A.       

You could check the doc I shared above for an example.

Comment: I’ve tried the approach and it still triggers Pipeline A with the default master branch when triggered by B.